# java RegEx for a particular word

Tags: java, regex

I have to check if input string contains specific word say "MASTER". String can be preceded or followed by any other characters but before and end of word "MASTER" should contain special char ";".

I tried following but no success.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\b;?MASTER(?:;\\w*)
```

Examples:

```
"MASTER" -- Expected output: True
"MASTER;" -- Expected output: True
"MASTER;abcd" -- Expected output: True
"MASTERabcd" -- Expected output: False
"abcMASTER" -- Expected output: False
"abc;MASTER;acx" -- Expected output: true
"xyz;lmn;abc;MASTER;acx" -- Expected output: true
```

Any thoughts!

I am ending up with following quick fix

```
String localValue = getValue(); // Input string
    final String nonEscapedValue = "MASTER"; //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(nonEscapedValue, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(localValue);
    boolean found = matcher.find();
    if (found) {
        // Ensure value ends with ";"
        if (localValue.length() > matcher.end()) {
            if (!(';' == localValue.charAt(matcher.end()))) {
                throw Exception;
            } 
        }

        // Ensure value starts with ";"
        if (matcher.start() > 0) {
            if (!(';' == localValue.charAt(matcher.start() - 1))) {
                throw Exception;
            }
        }
```

Thanks for all inputs

Comment: `/\bMASTER\b/` should be enough (except for checking multiple occurrences, which is easier to do externally).

Comment: "but before and end of word "MASTER" should contain special char ";" How come then your first example returns true?

Comment: @Biffen Agree with almas shaikh

Comment: @Arsh What?! Do you agree? Should I agree?

Comment: Your examples are inconsistent with each other and the text. Please correct this situation.

Comment: @Biffen I mean, if there are any characters (before or after "MASTER") should contain special char ";".  as shown in ex. abc;MASTER;acx

Comment: @Arsh `\b` will take care of that.

Comment: The comment is adding strange chars to expression... see fiddle link... I think he is asking for MASTER to appear surrounded by either a semi-colon, start of string, or end of string. And that it must also only appear once in the string. The expression above should do it. http://fiddle.re/6v0pd6

Comment: Why this question was put on hold as it is pretty clear what the user wants with examples and code!

Comment: Case 1. If string contains MASTER, then RegEx should should return true.  
Case 2. If string MASTER is surrounded any characters, then it should start and end with special char ";"